# Check HTTP server responses per second

Tags: http, nginx, server, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a server setup to respond to HTTP requests after searching a database, and what I would like to know is how reliable is it. In other words, I would like to somehow make thousands of requests simultaneously to see how much load it can handle.

Is there a way to see how many times does a server can respond to an HTTP request?

Comment: I found a quick way to make multiple requests using Curl: 
 `curl -s "http://yourappp.com/your_page_to_test.php?[1-10000]" ` in this case it will make 10,000 requests to the specified URL. http://servermonitoringhq.com/blog/how_to_quickly_stress_test_a_web_server